# DllRegisterServer in C:\WINNT\system32\inetsrv\inetmgr.dll failed

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, dll

Upon opening the Internet Information Services Manager I get the following error

```
"MMC could not create the snap-in"
```

Upon looking around I found that running the following command

```
regsvr32 %windir%\system32\inetsrv\inetmgr.dll
```

Should resolve the problem. In my case how ever it did not. Upon running the above command I get the following error instead

```
DllRegisterServer in C:\WINNT\system32\inetsrv\inetmgr.dll failed.
```

Just to clarify, yes the dll does exist in the said location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: "C:\WINNT"? Was this server upgraded from Windows 2000?

Comment: hi @joeqwerty not that I am aware of.

Comment: Well then Windows ought to be installed in C:\Windows, not C:\WINNT, if memory serves me right. In Windows NT and Windows 2000 the Windows directory was C:\WINNT. In Windows 2003 and forward the Windows directory is C:\Windows.

Comment: @joeqwerty Is correct... C:\WINNT means Server 2000 or NT. The only two possibilities are that this server was upgraded from 2000 or NT, or the originally installer *very dementedly* made the Windows installer install to the WINNT directory instead of the default. In any case, I'm not sure how it relates to your problem, but it is odd.